# VS Code touchpad scrolling moving cursor instead of page

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code on a Lenovo Yoga 710 laptop. My issue is when I scroll with two fingers on the touchpad the cursor moves up and down lines instead of moving the page and leaving the cursor where it is. This isn't happening in any other applications (tested with Word and notepad).

[Video showing VS Code vs Notepad scrolling](https://gyazo.com/bafb72c81c3c6c05cfe6ce9a65d86c65)

Anyone know how to change this? I can't find the setting anywhere in VS Code, and I haven't had this issue on other laptops.

Thanks!

### Edit

> This has been answered as not being an issue with VS Code, this is just a list of other issues to aide in future searches

- Scrolling not working in Slack: scrolling up results in first opening the editor for your last message then moving by highlighting each message

### Workaround solution

Following the instructions under [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2rfwR-IV-c) video worked for me on a Lenovo Yoga 710.

In case the link goes down here's the ELAN instructions:

1. Download the `ELAN UltraNav Driver` for the Yoga 370 from [here](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds120858)
2. Run the downloaded file to extract the contents to `C:/Drivers`
3. In Device Manager find the ELAN touchpad
4. Click on Update Driver > Browse my computer > Let me pick > Have Disk
5. Choose ETD.inf
6. Reboot

Comment: Try these 2 settings: `window.smoothScrollingWorkaround: true` and `window.titleBarStyle: native`. Any improvement?

Comment: @AlexMyers neither of those had any effect, thanks though!

Comment: Hey, any ideas for Lenovo Legion series? Mine is Y520 and couldn't find ultra nav driver for it. I tried installing the UltraNav drivers for other models but to no avail.

Comment: @ZenVentzi sorry pretty much all my knowledge of this issue is what's above. The solution for me involved using a driver that isn't meant for my laptop, so it might just be some trial-and-error with different drivers. Sorry I can't help more!

Comment: Update: my laptop must have had an update recently, because this just started being an issue again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no setting in VSCode to resolve this.

The [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17476) for this problem was closed since the issue is on Chromium's end. The [Chromium bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=784329&can=2&q=touchpad%20scroll&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) is still open and many people have commented on it regarding issues with their Lenovo laptops.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I'll look into making the arrow keys behave like the scroll wheel and see if that works, if you have any guidance in that direction it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 22):

I know this is an old post, but I was having a similar problem and wanted to share another solution in case anyone else comes across this like I did. The only thing that was sort of working was `Ctrl` + `Touchpad Scroll`, but that was really annoying and distracting.

I found another solution on the [Lenovo Support forum](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/Touchpad-not-two-finger-scrolling-properly-in-certain-apps/m-p/4303913?page=1#4304254) that solved my problem in 3 easy steps:

1. Open regedit.exe using run
2. Go to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Elantech\SmartPad`
3. Change `ScrollControl_Mode` from `0` to `1`

Comment: gave [+1]. many thanks @Amy. your comment saved my day.

Comment: With this very solution and setting the Scrolling speed (using ELAN UI) to 2/5 makes the touchpad seemingly smarter

Comment: This is working one, if owner of this question reads this comment or has notified then he should accept this answer. It is the best choice.

Comment: saved my day. good workaround

Answer (score 6):

Can you try this workaround, `Ctrl + Touchpad Scroll`. This one worked for me.

Comment: This is a good workaround on Windows. In OSX, this problem doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Just try some "Color Theme" and scrolling will work as expected.
I was also facing the same issue and when I changed the "Color Theme" the issue got fixed.

I'm currently using `@id:juliankaindl.deep-blue-theme` and moving the page instead of moving the cursor.

Comment: This seems like it might be a bug with that one theme. This is definitely an issue with below VSCode - I see the same issue with other apps like Slack that are built on top of a web browser